# Is there a way to recover pictures from a destroyed iPad?

Tags: recovery, ipad

An iPad mini from a friend was ran over by a car and it is completely non nonfunctional. I tried to connect it to charger to see if it was draining current but it is completely dead. There are some pictures on the iPad that I would have liked to recover. Is there a way to get back the files in such situation?

I'm thinking more of a hardware way, maybe by disconnecting the flash memory and using it in another device.

I Googled it but every article I found involved a partly functional iPad that could be connected to USB.

The iPad was never synced to iTune nor connected to iCloud.

Comment: The memory in the iPad cannot be read in this fashion you describe.  It sounds like you are out of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound - can't? I wouldn't say that. It's more like "if the ssd (flash chip) isn't broken, the expertise required to read its data will cost far more than you are likely willing to pay."

Comment: Thanks for migrating my question this SE site. I was not aware of its existence.